# keyup on mobile web apps seems to still not override a content block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, webview

I have some input that i am obtaining from the **keyup** event on an input textbox.

```
$(selector).keyup(function(){
  var str = $(this).val();
  var X = 2;
  var Y = 1;
  $(this).val(str.substring(X,Y));
});
```

When looking it in a standard webapp, **$(this).val()** doesnt have the newly pressed key in there.  WHich part of the lifecycle should i be looking at instead?  It seems that when doing it in a webapp, it seems to execute as planned, but not when using this in an iOS webview/mobile app

**Edit:**

it seems that there may in fact be a difference in the lifecycle for these listeners.  When doing keyup, it recognizes **$(this).val()** as the old content plus the new character, where as on the mobile device, it only recognzies the old content.  The new character is easily obtained by:

```
String.fromCharCode(event.which)
```

but at that point in the life cycle i cannot say to not remove it.  I was looking into the idea of maybe other events to tie into, as well as doing things like *event.preventDefault();* or *event.stopPropagation();* but i wasnt sure where to go.

Any idea how to work and handle this sort of event, or listener would be great.  With my current logic, it is needed for when i have the new content set.  Maybe a simple  *on("input")* might suffice?

Guidance highly appreshiated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Documentation on the page for keyup():

> For catching actual text entry, .keypress() may be a better choice.

Resolving my coding issue:

1) Change the event from keyup to keypress.
2) Do the following:

```
var reg = new RegExp("\\D");
if(reg.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){
  var str = $(this).val();
  var strArr = str.split("");
  // for handling when people maintain the press, 
  //    i created a range array to delete the range.
  strArr.splice(cRange[0], cRange[1]-cRange[0]+1); 
  str = strArr.join("");
  $(this).val(str);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```